# How to change accent colour in Ubuntu 22 via terminal

Tags: appearance

Ubuntu 22 [added a new feature to Settings](https://itsfoss.com/accent-color-ubuntu/) that allows the "accent colour" (orange by default) to be changed.

I'm wondering where this setting is stored and how I might be able to set it via the terminal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This changes to a different Yaru icon theme and corresponding gtk theme by changing the settings `org.gnome.desktop.interface icon-theme` and `org.gnome.desktop.interface gtk-theme`.

With the command line, e.g.:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface gtk-theme 'Yaru-bark'
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface icon-theme 'Yaru-bark'
```

The Yaru themes and icons are installed in `/usr/share/themes` and `/usr/share/icons`, and you can see the names by looking at the contents of these folders:

```
ls /usr/share/themes/ | grep Yaru
```

Comment: I don't understand the answer. He was asking about accent color, and you answered about icon theme.

Comment: @nonhocapito "This changes to a different Yaru icon theme and corresponding gtk theme" so the way to change accent color through the terminal is to change theme